# SQL syntax error with spring boot

Tags: mysql, sql, spring-boot

i'm using spring boot, i want to add new "champ", this is the code

```
                Champ c  = new Champ();
                c.setOrder(1);
                c.setType("RRRR");
                c.setStructurenotification("#AA");
                champservice.AddNewChamp(c);
```

the table `"champ"` have fields : `"idchamp", "structidstructurenotification" ,"type" and "order".`

but i get this error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'order, 
structidstructurenotification, type, idchamp)
 values (1, '#AA', 'RRRR', 0' at line 1
```

Comment: i think its because of the "order" it Ordery is a keyword for Order By..change the column name and try

Answer (score 3):

`Order` is a reserve word for `Order By`. Change the column name to some meaningful name and check.

Comment: Thnx...spent 4 days because of `Order` word. I was trying to create table name order

Comment: @AkshayTaru :) glad it helped